# Alguma boa tradução para "busk"?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Vi esse termo [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aluYo-FSqiw) e [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrMbOrW7NbY). Veja um exemplo:

> The famous singer secretly **busks** once in a while.

No sentido de o cantor famoso se apresentar em lugares públicos de forma discreta, disfarçada ou até mascarada de vez em quando.

Ponho também a [definição](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/busk) de "busk":

> to entertain by dancing, singing, or reciting on the street or in a
>   public place.

Não consigo achar uma boa tradução para a palavra nesse contexto:

> O cantor famoso secretamente **busks** de vez em quando.

- Como traduzir o verbo "to busk" no sentido de se apresentar em público?
- e como traduzir "secret busker" no contexto dos vídeos citados anteriormente?

Comment: *Busk* não é bem isso. Vê no [Oxford](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/busk?q=busk) ou no [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busk): é apenas atuar na rua, pedindo dinheiro a quem passa. A noção de "disfarçado, mascarado" no vídeo dos U2 vem de "in disguise": "U2 busks in NYC subway in disguise".

Comment: Eu usaria "mostrar-se" ou "preparar-se".

Comment: A definição de *busk* que acrescentaste é fundamental, mas eu tenho ainda uma sugestões. A etimologia da palavra é pouco relevante, porque o significado original tem pouco que ver com o atual, e portanto só distrai e confunde. A frase "No sentido de o cantor famoso [...]" também é um pouco confusa. Em vez dessa frase, eu dava logo a definição de *busk*, talvez seguida da tradução incompleta em português--"O cantor famoso *busks* secretamente em espaços públicos de vez em quando".

Comment: Fizeste bem em tirar o *busk* do etymoline. Na verdade em [*busker* é que o etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=busker) explica a origem de *busk* no sentido de atuar na rua. Não tou a dizer que incluas, mas poderás estar interessado em ver. Continuo a achar a tua 3ª frase, "No sentido de o cantor [...]", confusa, porque quem chega ali pode pensar que ela explica o sentido de *busk*, quando na verdade explica o sentido da frase anterior toda. Eu já votei na pergunta, portanto não ganhas mais pontos meus nesta pergunta, mas tou a dar a minha opinião.

Comment: Apresentação improvisada seria uma tradução...

Comment: Esse tipo de atitude é conhecida por serem executadas por "artistas de rua", ou também por "saltimbancos", mas não tem um verbo próprio para essa ação. Quanto a palavra saltimbancos, a palavra pode tanto representar um indivíduo de um grupo de pessoas quanto a si só de forma individual, que executa habilidades artísticas em locais públicos. Eu gosto da ideia de usá-la no contexto citado: "O cantor famoso secretamente age como saltimbanco de vez em quando."

Comment: Chegou a ler a minha resposta? Sobre a origem do termo e porque não é possivel traduzir, apesar de se possivel adaptar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que **busker** se refira a *apresentações de rua* conforme Wikipédia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_performance (como provavelmente você já sabe), portanto não vai ter tradução exata por na verdade ser uma *gíria*, conforme o [Wiki#Eymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_performance#Etymology):

> O termo "busking" foi anotado pela primeira vez na língua inglesa em meados da década de 1860 na Grã-Bretanha. O verbo de `busk`, da palavra `busker`, vem da palavra raiz espanhola buscar, com o significado de `buscar` (to seek) <sup>[[**1**]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busker)</sup>.
>
> A palavra espanhola buscar, por sua vez, evoluiu a partir da palavra indo-européia * "bhudh-skō" ("vencer, conquistar") [<sup>[**2**]</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6LB1acb).
>
> Foi usado para muitos atos de rua e título de um famoso livro espanhol sobre um deles, "El buscón". Hoje, a palavra ainda é usada em espanhol, mas principalmente relegada para profissionais do sexo feminino de rua, ou mulheres que procuram ser criadas como amantes privadas de homens casados.

---

Então na frase:

> The famous singer secretly busks once in a while.

Creio que poderia ser traduzida de maneira *adaptada*, já que não temos uma gíria equivalente, um exemplo seria:

> O famoso cantor apresenta-se fingindo ser *«um artista de rua»* de vez em quando

Ou:

> O famoso cantor apresenta-se fingindo ser *«um artista de rua»* as vezes

Ou:

> O famoso cantor se apresenta de vez em quando fingindo ser *«um artista de rua»*

Answer (score 0):

No caso não existe uma tradução perfeita. Se apresentar na rua de forma improvisada pode ser chamada de **apresentação mambembe** então fica difícil tentar traduzir um verbo com um adjetivo.

No contexto do exemplo dado acredito que a frase poderia ser traduzida como:

> O famoso cantor se **apresenta** (de improviso) anonimamente de vez em quando.

Também acredito que no contexto do exemplo *anonimamente* representa melhor a ideia do que *secretamente*.